Extract text from dxf that is not TEXT or MTEXT entity using ezdxf
I am trying to get numbers from a specific dxf file using ezdxf.
However, a query on the modelspace for msp.query('TEXT') or msp.query('MTEXT') yields no results, if I iterate over all entities, I can see they are all of type INSERT.
In the dxf file, I can see numbers next to a contour for every insert, and I can copy one insert into a new file, which results in the contour and the number being copied. However, I can not figure out where the information on the number is stored.
This is what the dxf file looks like viewed in LibreCAD:

Link to dxf file on google drive
Does anyone know where in the INSERT type entity the number might be stored? It is not in the entity.dxf.name, which yields a completely different string.

This is an unusual way to implement block reference attributes and does not use the ATTIB entity:
Use the ezdxf browse <file.dxf> command line tool to examine the DXF content.

going to the block definitions, each block reference has it's own block definition:

This script extracts the TEXT entities from the block definitions:

import ezdxf

doc = ezdxf.readfile("auflager.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()
for insert in msp.query("INSERT"):
    print(str(insert))
    for attrib in insert.attribs:
        # there are no ATTRIB entities:
        print("  ATTRIB: " + str(attrib.dxf.text))
    # each block reference has it's own block definition
    block = insert.block()
    if block is None:
        continue

    text = block.query("TEXT").first
    if text:
        print("  TEXT: " + str(text.dxf.text))


Output:
INSERT(#14E)
  TEXT: 1
INSERT(#14F)
  TEXT: 1
INSERT(#150)
  TEXT: 2
INSERT(#151)
  TEXT: 3
INSERT(#152)
  TEXT: 4
...

EDIT:
This is another tool to examine DXF files: https://alek-tron.com/DxfExplorer/
It runs in the browser and doesn't need Python nor ezdxf. The processing is done locally on your computer - no upload to a cloud service.

Thank you! Especially for the useful tip about the command line browse tool, that made debugging on different files way easier, too!

You'll need to iterate over the attributes held by the block reference (INSERT) entity - some examples of this technique may be found in the ezdxf documentation here:
https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/howto/content.html#howto-get-attribs

I should have mentioned that I already tried that - have you tried it with the attached dxf file? No attributes there.

I cannot access the DXF. You can inspect the type of entity by opening the DXF file in a plain text editor, such as Notepad++
